# The requested operation cannot be completed because the object has been garbage collected

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
The requested operation cannot be completed because the object has been garbage collected.
```

I get those error while loading the game state with Unity(c#) with:

```
File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd")
```

This is the sample I found that should work, but imo those error has nothing in common with those load operation cause those file size is just 600 bytes.

I'm new with those platform so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Is it on a build or in the editor? Please post on which platform the issue is happening - is it in the editor, a webplayer build, android etc?

Answer (score 1):

I see no way for `File.Exists` to trigger this, this error does have some in common with serialization. Are you sure that this code has triggered the problem? Also, check [this issue](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/the-requested-operation-cannot-be-completed-because-td4017899.html).

Are you using a breakpoint and inspecting anything with the debugger? If yes, then [this is an common error with mono](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1446). Unfortunately, Unity has an old Mono, and there is nothing you can do with it directly - only way is to try to not trigger this.